# XPath: limiting ancestor scope

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to create an xpath statement that finds the next element within a containing context that matches a particular class but not in other contexts. For example, given the following xml

```
<root>
  <a id="first" class="x"> 
    <b> 
      <c id="1" class="y"></c> 
    </b>
    <b> 
      <c id="2" class="y"></c>
    </b>
  </a>  
  <a id="second" class="x"> 
    <c id="3" class="y"></c> 
  </a> 
</root>
```

starting from id 1, I want to find the next y class element within the "first" a instance, but not anything from the "second" a instance. I have

```
//c[@id="1"]/ancestor::*/following-sibling::*[1]//descendant-or-self::*[@class="y"]
```

but this returns elements of id 2 and 3, when I only want id 2. I've seen the post titled "XPath: limit scope of result set" on stackoverflow, but it seems to be addressing a different problem or I don't understand that solution.

Comment: Currently, your XPath doesn't correspond to the sample XML i.e there is no `div` in the XML. Also `//[@id="1"]` is not valid expression, may be you mean `//c[@id="1"]`. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: you are correct. I simplified the xml example from my real code and didn't quite get the xpath translated properly. I've edited the question to correct it.

Comment: Great! A little bit more to fix though. Now your XPath would return nothing because there is no *ancestor `c`* from `c[@id="1"]`. At the same time it is written that the XPath *"returns elements of id 2 and 3"*. Could you provide an [mcve], something that we can easily run in XPath tester, like for example : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5555e3cd1a0fd29d9dcc2202ecce234c . Thanks again

Comment: Whole lotta fubar there. I've fixed the xml and xpath and verified it's behavior in firepath. Ideally I want to prevent the xpath search from leaving the current "a" when looking for a match. Assume a class "y" element can be any # of layers deep in the hierarchy.